# Limitations of PyTuple_SetItem

Tags: python, c, tuples, python-c-api

I have a Python extension module which creates a tuple as an attribute of another object, and sets items in the tuple.  Whenever I execute this module in Python, I keep getting the error `SystemError: bad argument to internal function`

After reading over the docs for `PyTuple`, and debugging my program for a few hours, I still couldn't figure out what the hell was going on.  Running my program through a debugger indicated the problem was occurring within a library call inside the Python interpreter.  So, finally, I looked at the Python source code, and at long last I realized the problem.  The `PyTuple_SetItem` function has an interesting restriction which I didn't know about, and can't find explicitly documented.

Here is the important function in the Python source (edited for clarity):

```
int PyTuple_SetItem(register PyObject *op, register Py_ssize_t i, PyObject *newitem)
{
    .....
    if (!PyTuple_Check(op) || op->ob_refcnt != 1) {
        Py_XDECREF(newitem);
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();
        return -1;
    }
    .....
}
```

The important line here is the condition **op->ob_refcnt != 1**.  So here's the problem: you can't even call `PyTuple_SetItem` unless the Tuple has a ref-count of 1.  It looks like the idea here is that you're never supposed to use `PyTuple_SetItem` except right after you create a tuple using `PyTuple_New()`.  I guess this makes sense, since Tuples are supposed to be immutable, after all, so this restriction helps keep your C code more in line with the abstractions of the Python type system.

However, I can't find this restriction documented anywhere.  Relevant docs seem to be [here](http://docs.python.org/c-api/intro.html#reference-count-details) and [here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/c-api/tuple.html?highlight=pytuple_getitem#PyTuple_SetItem), neither of which specify this restriction.  The docs basically say that when you call `PyTuple_New(X)`, all items in the tuple are initialized to `NULL`.  Since `NULL` is not a valid Python value, it's up to the extension-module programmer to make sure that all slots in the Tuple are filled in with proper Python values before returning the Tuple to the interpreter.  But it doesn't say anywhere that this must be done while the Tuple object has a ref count of 1.

So now, the problem is that I've basically coded myself into a corner because I wasn't aware of this (undocumented?) restriction on `PyTuple_SetItem`.  My code is structured in such a way that it's very inconvenient to insert items into the tuple until *after* the tuple itself has become an attribute of another object.  So, when it comes time to fill in the items in the tuple, the tuple already has a higher ref count.

I'll probably have to restructure my code, but I was seriously considering just temporarily setting the ref count on the Tuple to 1, inserting the items, and then restoring the original ref count.  Of course, that's a horrible hack, I know, and not any kind of permanent solution.  Regardless, I'd like to know if the requirement regarding the ref count on the Tuple is *documented* anywhere.  Is it just an implementation detail of CPython, or is it something that API users can rely on as expected behavior?

Comment: I'm curious as to more details on your use case and why do you increase the reference count before using the tuple. It will demonstrate better how this restriction is not appropriate. I'd like to add that the restriction doesn't protect against changing a tuple that you shouldn't either: You can accidentally add the tuples to a WeakKeyDictionary before finalizing their elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm quite sure that you can get around the restrictions by using `PyTuple_SET_ITEM` instead of `PyTuple_SetItem`. `PyTuple_SET_ITEM` is a macro defined in `tupleobject.h` as follows:

```
#define PyTuple_SET_ITEM(op, i, v) (((PyTupleObject*)(op))->ob_item[i] = v
```

So, if you are absolutely, definitely and utterly sure that:

1. `op` is a tuple object
2. you haven't initialized slot `i` in the tuple so far
3. you own a reference to `v` and you want to let the tuple steal it and
4. there is no chance of another Python object using the tuple for anything before you call `PyTuple_SET_ITEM`

then I guess you are safe to use `PyTuple_SET_ITEM`.

Answer (score 2):

The Python C API is *very* underdocumented and I would not be surprised if this restriction wasn't mentioned *anywhere*.

Of course, you should never be modifying tuples once something has gotten a hold of them regardless; either pass in the elements you need to put in the tuple, or use a list instead.

Comment: Conceptually, I think the restriction should be more like: *you should never modify a tuple **element** after you have already set the element.*  Saying you should never modify a tuple once something has gotten a hold of it seems like a less meaningful restriction to me.