# How can I create a circular reference of tuples?

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, cpython, circular-reference

For historical reasons (read: horrible `type(t) == tuple` checks), I find myself needing to freeze a circular graph as a collection of `tuple` objects. This, obviously, isn't ideal:

```
>>> head = ("head", None)
>>> a = ("a", ("b", ("c", head)))
>>> head[1] = a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    head[1] = a
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

I, however, am not really a great believer in `TypeError`s, and suspect that, through implementation-specific hackery, this can be done.

- How can I produce this monstrosity without risking going Out of Bounds or causing other C Undefined Behaviour?
- Can the circular dependency freeing part of the Garbage Collector cope with such a thing?

Comment: Apparently some people have had success with ctypes (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/6111843/674039), but it always segfaults for me.  And I have no idea how `hash(a)` is supposed to work for your hypothetical-frozen-circular-graph-stored-in-a-tuple, it might get stuck in an infinite-loop. Why don't you just use a proper graphing library such as networkX, and define graph/node serializers if needed?

Comment: @wim Why not just use a `list`? It isn't actually representing a graph, but a state diagram. And it's a terrible piece of code that should be burned, but can't be just yet. I'm cutting it up and feeding it into the furnace where I can. (Your point about `hash(a)` is valid, though; this might not actually be possible depending on what the code uses the `tuple` for.)

Comment: Oh, my. Find some other horrible hack, I beg you. How about `sed 's/type(t) == tuple/True/'`?

Comment: Get creative. Override `type()` and special case the return value for `t`. Come on, I believe in you.

Comment: @JohnKugelmansupportsMonica The last time I tried modifying `__builtins__`, it ended _really_ badly. But I suppose it can't exactly be _worse_ than doing this. In fact, it's probably safer to dynamically modify `__builtins__.__dict__`'s type to a `dict` subclass with empty `__slots__`, implement `__getitem__` and replace `type`'s implementation just for the horrible module… I think I've got the code for that lying around somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I, however, am not really a great believer in TypeErrors, and suspect that, through implementation-specific hackery, this can be done.

Sadly, you are correct:

```py
from ctypes import Structure, c_ssize_t, c_void_p, py_object, pythonapi

pythonapi.Py_DecRef.argtypes = py_object,


def mutable(tup):
    # We are generating this class dynamically because the size of ob_item
    # varies according to the size of the given tuple
    class PyTupleObject(Structure):
        _fields_ = [('ob_refcnt', c_ssize_t),
                    ('ob_type', c_void_p),
                    ('ob_size', c_ssize_t),
                    ('ob_item', py_object * len(tup))]

        @classmethod
        def from_tuple(cls, tup):
            instance = cls.from_address(id(tup))
            # Save a reference to tup on the instance, as we are using it directly from memory
            # and don't want it to be garbage collected
            instance.original = tup
            return instance

        def __setitem__(self, idx, val):
            # Replacing a value in self.ob_item doesn't decref the old value but does indref the new value
            pythonapi.Py_DecRef(self.ob_item[idx])
            self.ob_item[idx] = val

        def __getitem__(self, idx):
            return self.ob_item[idx]

        def __iter__(self):
            return iter(self.ob_item)

        def __len__(self):
            return len(self.ob_item)

        def __contains__(self, val):
            return val in self.ob_item

    return PyTupleObject.from_tuple(tup)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tup = (None,)
    mut_tup = mutable(tup)
    mut_tup[0] = tup
    print(tup is tup[0]) # Outputs "True"
```

> How can I produce this monstrosity without risking going Out of Bounds or causing other C Undefined Behaviour?

We prevent out of bounds access by defining the member `ob_item` to be `py_object * len(tup)`.

> Can the circular dependency freeing part of the Garbage Collector cope with such a thing?

No! Tuples are supposed to be immutable, and therefore are not expected to have a cyclic reference to themselves. That's why they don't implement the `tp_clear` method, that is used by the python garbage collector to break reference cycles and collect the involved garbages. More details [here](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_clear)

Comment: Warning: calling `hash` on the resulting tuple, or using it in a set or as a dictionary key, will give you a stack overflow.

Comment: Doesn't this create a new `PyTupleObject` class each time `mutable(tup)` is run? (Yes, that is definitely the biggest problem with this code, and not that it exists at all.)

Comment: It does, because the size of the struct varies according to the length of the tuple. I didn't find a way to create a variable sized structure class :)